# Transition Hooks in Angular Js are compatible with IE? If yes then from which version?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser, hook, transition

I am trying to use transition hooks in angularJs they work fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox even Edge but not IE.

How can I check compatibility of transition hooks with IE and its version?
I tried running it on IE 11.